# Descending Order for SortCursor Class

Tags: java, android, sorting

So I've been using this great resource class i found online to Sort two cursors based on an column:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.4.4_r1/core/java/com/android/internal/database/SortCursor.java

The onMove function of this Cursor seems to be doing the sorting between the two cursors:

```
@Override
    public boolean onMove(int oldPosition, int newPosition)
    {
        if (oldPosition == newPosition)
            return true;
        /*
         * Find the right cursor
         * Because the client of this cursor (the listadapter/view) tends
         * to jump around in the cursor somewhat, a simple cache strategy
         * is used to avoid having to search all cursors from the start.
         * TODO: investigate strategies for optimizing random access and
         * reverse-order access.
         */
        int cache_entry = newPosition % ROWCACHESIZE;
        if (mRowNumCache[cache_entry] == newPosition) {
            int which = mCursorCache[cache_entry];
            mCursor = mCursors[which];
            if (mCursor == null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onMove: cache results in a null cursor.");
                return false;
            }
            mCursor.moveToPosition(mCurRowNumCache[cache_entry][which]);
            mLastCacheHit = cache_entry;
            return true;
        }
        mCursor = null;
        int length = mCursors.length;
        if (mLastCacheHit >= 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (mCursors[i] == null)
                    continue;
                mCursors[i].moveToPosition(mCurRowNumCache[mLastCacheHit][i]);
            }
        }
        if (newPosition < oldPosition || oldPosition == -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (mCursors[i] == null)
                    continue;
                mCursors[i].moveToFirst();
            }
            oldPosition = 0;
        }
        if (oldPosition < 0) {
            oldPosition = 0;
        }
        // search forward to the new position
        int smallestIdx = -1;
        for (int i = oldPosition; i <= newPosition; i++) {
            String smallest = "";
            smallestIdx = -1;
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                if (mCursors[j] == null || mCursors[j].isAfterLast()) {
                    continue;
                }
                String current = mCursors[j].getString(mSortColumns[j]);
                if (smallestIdx < 0 || current.compareToIgnoreCase(smallest) < 0) {
                    smallest = current;
                    smallestIdx = j;
                }
            }
            if (i == newPosition)
                break;
            if (mCursors[smallestIdx] != null) {
                mCursors[smallestIdx].moveToNext();
            }
        }
        mCursor = mCursors[smallestIdx];
        mRowNumCache[cache_entry] = newPosition;
        mCursorCache[cache_entry] = smallestIdx;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (mCursors[i] != null) {
                mCurRowNumCache[cache_entry][i] = mCursors[i].getPosition();
            }
        }
        mLastCacheHit = -1;
        return true;
    }
```

I'm not familiar with how cursors work but I was wondering how I would modify the onMove function such that the sorting of the two cursors would be sorted in desceding order rather than the default ascending order?

Any ideas would help! Thanks!

Comment: See everywhere it says smallest?  Change it to largest and reverse any < to > and vice versa.  That will get you 95% of the way there.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?